# QOpenGLWidget resize results in incorrect viewport size

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, resize, viewport

I have some issues with my `QOpenGLWidget` resizing functionality. Obviously, I am aiming for a new viewport with the correct amount of pixels and a scene centered in the actual center of my window. But these two things are off somehow.

Here are some images:

Initial one:

[image: Correct]

Scaled in Y:

[image: Scaled in Y]

Scaled in X:

[image: Scaled in X]

The result is pixelated and translated. For me it looks like the GL viewport has the correct amount of pixels, but is scaled to the top and to the right (if the (0,0) is defined as the bottom left corner).

Here is my code:

```
void GLWidget::initializeGL() {
    QOpenGLFunctions::initializeOpenGLFunctions();
    glClearColor(0.7f, 0.75f, 0.8f, 1.0f);
    glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
}

void GLWidget::resizeGL(int w, int h) {
    qreal aspect = qreal(w) / qreal(h ? h : 1);
    const qreal zNear = 3, zFar = 7, fov = 3.14/6;
    //I will leave this at it is. This cannot cause the viewport translation
    mGraphics->setProjectionPers(fov, aspect, zNear, zFar);
}

void GLWidget::paintGL() {

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);

    //actual Drawing
    //...
}
```

The resizeGL is called with the correct values. What am I doing wrong for having a pixelated and translated image when I run this piece of code?

Comment: I can't help because I don't see the glViewport call. You must call glViewport in resizeGL. Also I don't know what mGraphics->setProjectionPers does

Comment: I tried calling glViewport myself with glViewport(0,0,w,h). Did not change anything.
Actually this call is performed by Qt before it calls the resizeGL according to the Qt reference.
Regarding the setProjectionPers. This creates a projection matrix via glm, which is passed to the shaders in the actual drawing section. 
If I set the aspect (the only variable value there) to 1.0f the objects are centered initially and wander off, when I resize the window.

Comment: Another thing. The initial size does not matter. If its 100x100 or 1000x100 or 500x500 the objects are always centered in the beginning with smooth edges. As soon as I resize the window, the scene is moving away from the center and they get pixelated

Comment: @Fabio: People. please, for the love of little kittens, don't do any glViewport calls in the resize handler. Calls to glViewport (and also setting projection and transformation matrices) **always** go into the drawing code; no exceptions! Doing it differently just leads to pain and suffering in the long run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For whatever reason this was in the header file of my QOpenGLWidget decendant:

```
void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent* ev) {
    resizeGL(width(), height());
}
```

This pretty much skips all the resize logic of the QOpenGLWidget class.